# How to make exception messages translatable in a Symfony 4 user checker?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm checking if a user is enabled to let them login and if not, show them an error message in the language of their locale. It's a Symfony 4.2 app. So here's my user checker (which works):

```
<?php
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User as AppUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface {
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
    /* Make the message translatable */
        if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(
                'This account has not been activated.'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The usual approach to translating strings in Symfony 4 would require a change in the signature:

```
public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user, TranslatorInterface $translator)
```

That would work in the functions I define in the controllers but this user checker is registered as a service that is used in a firewall so we get an error:

```
FatalErrorException
Compile Error: Declaration of App\Security\UserChecker::checkPostAuth(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface $user, App\Security\TranslatorInterface $translator) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface::checkPostAuth(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface $user)
```

I can't find documentation about any other way either that would work with Symfony 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way Symfony does this this, is translating the message only when it is displayed during the rendering of a template, e.g. in the [login form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) you have this:

```
{% if error %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Another approach could be to hook into Symfony's event system and translate the exception inside an EventListener that catches the `AuthenticationFailureEvent` by listening to `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants a solution although the question is a bit old but it might help someone.
simply we can inject the translator component via the dependency injection in the contractor and not via the method `UserChecker` because it have a specific signature defined in the `UserCheckerInterface`.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User as AppUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

final class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    private TranslatorInterface $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user): void
    {
        if (!$user instanceof AppUser) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->isVerified()) {
            // the message passed to this exception is meant to be displayed to the user
            throw new CustomUserMessageAccountStatusException($this->translator->trans('account_inactive'));
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user): void
    {
    }
}
```